# onClick event not working when changing the parameter name

Tags: reactjs

[image]

---

So I have an event on Click . it works when i pass "id" as parameter but doesn't work when i pass "key" , even though all the properties of id and key are same(see the image).
below is the method
I have already made all the properties of ID and KEY same , but it seems not to work.

---

```
onClick={ () => this.props.onDelete(this.props.key)}
```

VS

```
onClick={ () => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  What debugging have you done?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what problem you are observing.

Answer (score 3):

`key` is a reserved prop in a React component. You won't be able to access it in child component. If you need it, give it some other name.

Answer (score 2):

The `key` property is used by React under the hood, and is not exposed to us inside the component.

You can see more info in the official documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings 
(`Keys serve as a hint to React but they don’t get passed to your components. If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name`)